# XSL-FO external graphic not rotating properly

Tags: apache, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I've suddenly developed the problem where the graphics in my resulting PDF don't have the proper rotation, or orientation.  Photos taken with an iPhone in portrait orientation have started appearing in the PDF in landscape mode.  The landscape items stay properly in landscape, but portraits also resolve to landscape.  As I say, this is a new problem, and I haven't made any changes to any of the related software since November.  The only remotely connected change, is that I've updated my Java, about a week ago.

So my question is, is there any setting about honoring the EXIF rotation information, or something along those lines?  I can't go in on an image-by-image basis and set a forced rotation, and in the past, the proper orientation just happened.

```
<fo:external-graphic src="../../MMSimages/IMG_9162.jpg" content-height="1.8in"/>
```

This code, works on images from a a few days ago, but not on any newer images.
Using saxonhe9-2-0-6j/saxon9he.jar as my processor, and FOP 1.1

Comment: Have you excluded any changes in your iPhone that might cause the problem?

Comment: It's actually gotten more strange.  Screenshots that I take, show in the proper rotation, as do pics sent to me by others.  It's only photos that I take, that have the constant landscape orientation.  No, I'm still on 5.1, so there haven't been any changes to the core software.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a hardware issue: if there's a problem with the acceleration sensors in the iPhone, the orientation of the picture will no longer be correctly added to the picture's EXIF data. 
Is the issue only with pictures you've taken recently, or do older pictures you took on the iPhone have the same problem? 
What happens when you open the pictures in a photo editing program?

Comment: I've looked at images, both old and new, and they all have orientation values, but FOP seems to ignore them.